# why autoFocus doesn't work when re-render a componnet

Tags: reactjs

below is the source code:

```
export class Editor extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         name: "",
         price: "",
         autoFocus: true
      }
   }

   handleChange = (event) => {
      this.setState(state => state[event.target.name] = event.target.value);
   }

   handleAdd = () => {
      this.props.callback(this.state);
      this.setState({ name: "", category: "", price: "" });
   }

   render() {
      return <React.Fragment>
         <div className="form-group p-2">
            <label>Name</label>                         {/* set autoFocus here*/}
            <input className="form-control" name="name" autoFocus={this.state.autoFocus} value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} /> 
         </div>
         <div className="form-group p-2">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input className="form-control" name="price" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.handleChange} />
         </div>
         <div className="text-center">
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleAdd}>
               Add
            </button>
         </div>
      </React.Fragment>
   }
}
```

I set the first input's autoFocus to be true, so when the form is first displayed, the input gets focus, which is good.

but after I click the button, `Editor` component's render method called due to its state changes, so I expect the first input to gain focus again, however, it is not, but button still gets the focus, why the input doesn't refocus in this case?